# method return type from a class variable

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Given the following class:

```
  ...

  Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumType;

  public MyClass(Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumType) {
    super();

    this.enumType=enumType;

  ...
```

How do i define a method that returns an Enum of the "enumType" class?

I need something like:

```
public enumType getValue(){
  ...
}
```

,but this doesn't work ..

Comment: First, don't use wildcards.

Comment: you cant not have enumType as a return value!

Comment: ye, i just kept trying to produce an acceptable code, this was one. Assuming i don't need the getValue() method, how can the above code be written better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a type parameter instead of a wildcard. For example:

```
class MyClass<T extends Enum<T>> {
    private Class<T> enumType;

    public MyClass(Class<T> enumType) {
        this.enumType = enumType;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

*edit* In response to your comment, here's a method that lists all constants of an arbitrary `enum`:

```
public <E extends Enum<E>> void showEnumValues(Class<E> e) {
    for (E value : e.getEnumConstants())
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Given your code, how can i refer to the class of T? I need to iterate on all values of the T enum.

Your way i bump into another problem, which is definition.

MyClass<MyEnum> myRef = new MyClass(MyEnum.class);

I don't want to post the parameter twice, but i run into the problem , that i can't refer to T's any property in any way in the constructor, if i don't give the class as a parameter.

Comment: See my edit for how to iterate through the constants of an `enum`.

Comment: same problem persists. I don't want to pass e, its definite by the generic parameter. That's the way i iterate on them, and thats the reason that MyClass in my code is not generic but rather takes a Class argument in constructor.

Comment: You cannot get around this without passing the `Class<T>` for the `enum`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to actually specify a variable inside your generic, not just use wildcards everywhere. Then it's just like this:

```
public class MyClass<E extends EnumType<E>> {
    Class<E> enumType;
    E value;

    public MyClass(Class<E> enumType) {
        this.enumType = enumType;
    }

    public E getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used it like this, but this way i need to create a new instance like this: MyClass<MyEnum> Myref = MyClass(MyEnum.class); I don't intend to pass an argument twice in a definition for various reasons like the whole point of MyClass gets questionable which is the best way to create a ComboBox which contains the values of an Enum. In other words, how do i refer to MyEnum.class(when it's generic) ? i found no way ..

Comment: @AttilaNeparáczki You're not actually passing it twice, just once; the generic type is only checked at compile time and then erased. You'll notice that all of the enum-based generic collections (like `EnumMap`) have the same requirement.

Comment: Thank you. There were two very similar answers, i accepted the other one, hope for no problems :)